# Storing a generic conforming to an associated type inside A collection

Tags: swift

I am trying to store a generic who uses an an associated type, however when trying to create a type which should conform to the generic type I describe in the generic list at the top of class A, but I get the error.

"Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(B)'"

How can I properly declare the generic so that this code works?

```
class A<DataType: Any, AssociatedType: Runable> where 
AssociatedType.DataType == DataType {
  var array = Array<AssociatedType>()

  func addAssociatedValue(data: DataType) {
    array.append(B(data: data))
  }

  func runOnAll(with data: DataType) {
    for item in array {
      item.run(with: data)
    }
  }
}
class B<DataType>: Runable {
  init(data: DataType) { }
  func run(with: DataType) { }
}

protocol Runable {
  associatedtype DataType
  func run(with: DataType)
}
```

I am also using Swift 4.2 so if there is a solution that uses one of the newer Swift features that will also work as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` conforms to `Runnable`, yes, but you can't put it into an array that's supposed to store `AssociatedType`s. Because the actual type of `AssociatedType` is decided by the caller of the class, not the class itself. The class can't say, "I want `AssociatedType` to always be `B`". If that's the case, you might as well remove the `AssociatedType` generic parameter and replace it with `B`. The caller can make `AssociatedType` be `Foo` or `Bar` or anything conforming to `Runnable`. And now you are forcing to put a `B` in.

I think you should rethink your model a bit. Ask yourself whether you really want `AssociatedType` as a generic parameter.

You could consider adding another requirement for `Runnable`:

```
init(data: DataType)
```

And add `required` to `B`'s initializer. This way, you could write `addAssociatedValue` like this:

func addAssociatedValue(data: DataType) {
    array.append(AssociatedType(data: data))
  }

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in my use case as in the non-simplified code, B class is private implementation and has two generics one of which i'm trying to hide from A class with the protocol. Still a good answer for the code I provided, I may post a new question with a more restricting code sample.